# ssh + here document – does Ctrl+C get to remote side?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash-scripting, wait

As part of a series of tasks I have to do, I have to build a bash script that accesses a remote computer, executes 3 commands, waits for a process to end through a `SIGINT` (or simply end) and then do some cleanup afterwards.

Currently, I'm using this code:

```
#! /bin/bash

# local preparations
# ...

ssh -t $USER@remote.far <<-'COMMANDS'

    echo "Preparing execution"

    java -jar execute.jar &
    executePID=$!

    echo "Ready."
    echo "CTRL+C to clean and close"

    trap "kill $executePID" INT HUP
    wait $executePID

    #cleanup code here

    echo "done. Logging out"
    sleep 2
    logout
COMMANDS

# Final local cleanup
```

This code seem to work just find until `wait` (builtin) command. `wait` seems to be consuming all commands that come after it and so, when I try to send a `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), it seems to fail to execute the trap content and all the cleanup code.

How can I fix this so it works the way I expect?

I'm not allowed to split this bash file into multiple ones and I'm not allowed to create any scripts on the remote computer even if temporary.
Both computers are running the same flavor of Linux.

Comment: What if you move the `wait $executePID` outside of the ssh command? You could then replace $executePID with the PID of the ssh command instead of the Java command. Also, are you saying that if you execute this script & ctrl-c it then you want it to run some additional commands to cleanup the remote host? If so, then what you need to look at creating your own trap handling function using `trap ctrl_c INT` and then writing a function called ctrl_c that will be called if a SIGINT is triggered [see this blog post](https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash).

Comment: Further to my previous comments, do you know that the script is definitely hanging at the wait? Your java command does not launch the command in the background (by finishing the line with `&`) so what might be happening is that your script launches the java process and that is where the ctrl-c is hitting the command. Are you definitely seeing the 'Ready'  & 'CTRL-C' echos when you execute your script?

Comment: @stuts Sorry for the delay. I know where it is hanging because I made some debug outputs to console for the bash and some debug to file for the java program. The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is being sent to java and the java program is terminating as expected. You got a point about the missing `&` in that example script. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

It's not about `wait`. I think this is what happens:

You use `<<`, so `stdin` of `ssh` is redirected to some descriptor through which the entire *here document* flows.

[This other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161878/108618) explains how `ssh` is able to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when `-t` is used. This is what matters:

> On the client side, `ssh` will try to set the `tty` used by `stdin` to "raw" mode […] Setting raw mode means that characters that would normally send signals (such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) are instead just inserted into the input stream.

In your case it's not the same `stdin` your local shell uses. `tty` used by your local shell is left intact, it is never set to "raw" mode.

So when you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it acts locally and terminates `ssh`. At this moment the remote side gets `SIGHUP`. Your `trap` works and kills `java`. I think there's a pitfall here: a `trap` executes some code in response to a given signal but it doesn't prevent the signal from having its normal effect. Therefore it looks to me your `java` would be killed even without a `trap` because it's a job of the shell that gets terminated in response to `SIGHUP`.

The shell that gets terminated stops reading and interpreting its `stdin`. That's why everything that follows `wait` is discarded.

---

#### Solution

```
commands() { cat <<-'COMMANDS'

    cleanup() {
    # cleanup code here
    echo "Done. Logging out"
    sleep 2
    logout
    }

    echo "Preparing execution"

    java -jar execute.jar &
    executePID=$!

    echo "Ready."
    echo "CTRL+C to clean and close"

    trap "kill $executePID; cleanup" INT HUP
    wait $executePID

    cleanup
COMMANDS

}

stty raw -echo; cat <(commands) - | ssh -t $USER@remote.far; stty -raw echo
```

The last line is the actual command. First we prepare `tty` so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> cannot act locally. Then we concatenate commands and standard input, we pass it to the remote shell. I cannot do this with *here document* directly, the `command` function is a workaround (it would be easier to use a regular file but you said you cannot use more than one). After `ssh` and `cat` exit we set the `tty` to its normal state.

Having pseudo-terminal is essential so make sure `ssh -t` works (use `-tt` if needed).

The remote shell must read (buffer) all the commands from `commands`, only then it can get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when you press it. I guess this means you cannot have too much code after `wait`. Additionally whatever you want to do after `SIGINT` must be run from inside the `trap`. These are the reasons I used a single `cleanup` function that does it all.

The code is not foolproof. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> too early or multiple times and you'll find yourself in the remote shell or with somewhat "broken" local `tty`. In this latter case use the command `reset` to reset your `tty`.

You must press a key (e.g. <kbd>Enter</kbd>) after you see "Connection to … closed." The reason is `cat` won't notice the pipe is broken (due to `ssh` being no more) until it tries to write something to it.

---

#### Alternative

If for any reason the above solution doesn't work for you, use this simpler alternative. The *here document* is exactly as before. In this case we don't mess with `tty`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> terminates local `ssh` as it does with your original code. The difference (with respect to your code) is the `trap` does the cleaning. I think it would be enough to trap `SIGHUP` only.

```
ssh -t $USER@remote.far <<-'COMMANDS'

    cleanup() {
    # cleanup code here
    echo "Done. Logging out"
    sleep 2
    logout
    }

    echo "Preparing execution"

    java -jar execute.jar &
    executePID=$!

    echo "Ready."
    echo "CTRL+C to clean and close"

    trap "kill $executePID; cleanup" INT HUP
    wait $executePID

    cleanup
COMMANDS
```

Note: when the `trap` is triggered `cleanup` echoes a message but you won't see it because your local `ssh` is already disconnected. You will see the message only if `java` exits without the `trap`. Still your cleanup code (`# cleanup code here`) should be executed.

Comment: Looks great! Thank you! I'll try it when I can and then I'll try to report back on it.