# Linux trap signals to handle SSH connection dropped/killed

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I’ve got a command in an npm script that SSHes into a remote build server and runs a Bash script. The script sets up a lockfile and a `trap` call to delete the lockfile when the script exits.

I’m cancelling the operation with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in both cases.

```
LOCKFILEPATH="/tmp/env_app.lock"
# cleanup function just deletes $LOCKFILEPATH
function mutex() {
  if [ -f "$LOCKFILEPATH" ]; then
    echo -e "\n\n${redtext}Build already in progress! Exiting.${resettext}\n\n";
    exit 1;
  else
    touch $LOCKFILEPATH;
    trap cleanup EXIT;
  fi
}
```

This works fine when you first SSH into the host to run it, but the trap is not working when you send the command over SSH with

```
ssh hostname command
```

I tried adding to the trap command to run for more signals, but these don't seem to work either:

```
 trap cleanup EXIT SIGHUP SIGKILL SIGTERM SIGINT
```

What should I be doing here?

I also set up a [simpler script](https://pastebin.com/VTPg9GAT) and it seemed to work fine when executing it manually over SSH. Maybe there's added layers when I’m running it using an npm script? The npm script is:

```
"deploy": "ssh HOSTNAME ''deploy-script $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) stage $npm_package_config_deploy_target yes''",
```

which just checks the current branch name and uses that to deploy on the build host. Same as

```
"deploy": "ssh HOSTNAME ''deploy-script CURRENTBRANCH stage APPNAME''",
```

UPDATE: Adding a force tty `-t` to the npm script seems to have fixed it. Confusing since I didn't need that for the simple script case. Maybe I'm spawning too many sub processes in the large script (too much to paste here without redacting a bunch) so it requires a tty to trigger the cleanup trap.

```
"deploy": "ssh -t HOSTNAME ''deploy-script CURRENTBRANCH stage APPNAME''",
```

Comment: If `-t` fixes the problem, doesn't that mean the trap only runs when you hit CTRL-C as a user? What if you SSH connection drops? Does the `trap` still work then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
ssh hostname command
```

and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you terminate the local `ssh`. The `command` still runs on the remote side, it never gets your keystroke. This is different with `-t`. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161878/108618) for explanation. The relevant fragment:

> On the client side, `ssh` will try to set the tty used by stdin to "raw" mode, and `sshd` on the remote host will allocate a pseudo-tty […] if you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it will be sent to the remote host, where the command will likely receive `SIGINT` […]. The remote `sshd` then closes the connection, and `ssh` reports `Connection to remotehost closed`.

Therefore use:

```
ssh -t hostname command
```

and your `command` (not the local `ssh`) will get `SIGINT` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

---

This may get even more interesting. Compare [*ssh + here document – does Ctrl+C get to remote side?*](https://superuser.com/q/1141887/432690)

Comment: This is what I saw in practice, but a ctrl-c does stop execution of the remote host command. Or is this just a temporary continuation and it exits when it loses the socket or something? Logging output stops immediately so it gets some sort of SIG.

Comment: Also, I didn't need -t for the simple script linked to above. So there's subtlety to it.

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure. I suspect it may have something to do with `stdin` or so. In my tests remote `sleep` survives when local `ssh` exits, but remote `cat` exits. Each of them exits on Ctrl+C when `-t` is used.

Comment: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` - there should be a way to dial with that in scripts