# "Ctrl + c" combination works different on different SSH clients

Tags: linux, ssh, keyboard-shortcuts, putty, kill

While I using MobaXTerm I can make a ssh connection to remote machine and I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination to kill a process that works on remote machine. But while I use PuTTy I can make a ssh to remote machine but the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination works on local machine and kills ssh session.

It wasn't like that at first times but I think so something has changed (it is not my personal computer, it's a work computer). I cannot use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination to kill any process on remote machine via PuTTy. How can I change this setting to get same with MobaXTerm (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kills the process on remote machine, not the ssh session on local machine).

For clear anything, the scenario is like this:

1. I connect to our main Linux server (host1) -that open to everywhere- from my PC (windows). I go to anywhere must from here.
2. I make ssh to client1 from this terminal machine (host1). Because there is no way to make ssh to client1 (Linux) from local pc directly.
3. While I working on client1 if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from any reason I lose my ssh connection between host1 and client1 and I fall to host1. And the output is: "Killed by signal 2"

   ```
   [client1 ~]#                   <--   I hit Ctrl+C here
   [client1 ~]# Killed by signal 2.
   [host1 ~]#
   ```

Edit: I detected another issue about this problem. Maybe It be a clue:
If I login to host1 with using GUI of MobaXTerm, same problem is happenning (killing ssh session). But, if I use command line to make ssh on local to host1 (ssh host1 command) problem doesn't happen on client1. And If the problem will be happened the "dzdo" command hangs while checking the password until I hit enter. This hanging problem is exist on PuTTy already.

Edit & Note: I deleted PuTTy settings with using regedit (delete \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham) and everything is OK. But I won't be learned the reason of the problem anymore.

Comment: No. While I'm on server named "host1" and make connection to "client1" and when I hit Ctrl+C the ssh connection ends and I fall to host1 again. But just on PuTTy and other clients based on PuTTy. not MobaXTerm.

Comment: I still don't know your exact setup but maybe [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1288719/432690) and links therein will give you some clue.

Comment: I added a use case for clear everything @KamilMaciorowski thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you follow my link and reach [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161878/108618)? What exact command do you use to connect from `host1` to `client1`?

Comment: Yes I did but there is no change. I use just ssh. I added a last thing to question. I deleted register to turn to default settings and this workaround is worked.